# Freeswitch spandsp.conf.xml Tone settings

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I'm using spandsp for tone detection, I'm looking for some guidance in configuring SIT, REORDER and BUSY tone in **spandsp.conf.xml** for Brazil.

Frequency (**freq1/freq2**) params in HZ is understandable, and **min/max** params *seems* to be tone duration. Where can I find these values for Brazil?

This is the US sample:

```
<descriptor name="1">
       <tone name="CED_TONE">
         <element freq1="2100" freq2="0" min="700" max="0"/>
       </tone>
       <tone name="SIT">
         <element freq1="950" freq2="0" min="256" max="400"/>
         <element freq1="1400" freq2="0" min="256" max="400"/>
         <element freq1="1800" freq2="0" min="256" max="400"/>
       </tone>

       <tone name="RING_TONE" description="North America ring">
         <element freq1="440" freq2="480" min="1200" max="0"/>
       </tone>

       <tone name="REORDER_TONE">
         <element freq1="480" freq2="620" min="224" max="316"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="168" max="352"/>
         <element freq1="480" freq2="620" min="224" max="316"/>
       </tone>
       <tone name="BUSY_TONE">
         <element freq1="480" freq2="620" min="464" max="536"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="464" max="572"/>
         <element freq1="480" freq2="620" min="464" max="536"/>
       </tone>
     </descriptor>
```

Here are the Brazil tones according to ITU standard:

http://www.itu.int/pub/T-SP-OB.781-2003

But there is no mention for **min/max** values.
Looking to see if someone can provide a sample configuration for Brazil for spandsp.conf.xml or some insights.

Comment: The above sample if for `<!-- North America -->`, I think Brazil comes under south america. So If you could find for `south america` then i might fit for Brazil
https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/conf/vanilla/autoload_configs/spandsp.conf.xml

Comment: Your link is the sample file which I already referred and contains no South America, just US, Germany, UK.

Answer (score 0):

After turning debugging options for **spandsp.conf.xml**
I found the following settings for Brazil in Asterisk **indications.conf**

```
busy = 425/250,0/250
congestion = 425/250,0/250,425/750,0/250
```

Debugging Freeswitch tone using `<descriptors debug-level="2">` in **spandsp.conf.xml** using **fs_cli**:

```
2016-08-21 09:27:37.502533 [DEBUG] mod_spandsp_dsp.c:705 Tone segment: f1 = 1, f2 = -1, duration = 240
2016-08-21 09:27:37.762531 [DEBUG] mod_spandsp_dsp.c:705 Tone segment: f1 = -1, f2 = -1, duration = 256
2016-08-21 09:27:38.002616 [DEBUG] mod_spandsp_dsp.c:705 Tone segment: f1 = 1, f2 = -1, duration = 272
2016-08-21 09:27:38.262532 [DEBUG] mod_spandsp_dsp.c:705 Tone segment: f1 = -1, f2 = -1, duration = 240
```

**f1** and **f2** are the Frequency and **min** and **max** is the Tone duration configurable in Min and Max. For the example above:

```
   <tone name="BUSY_TONE">
     <element freq1="425" freq2="0" min="224" max="240"/>
     <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="240" max="256"/>
     <element freq1="425" freq2="0" min="240" max="272"/>
     <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="224" max="240"/>
   </tone>
```